# JADE node js to mark an option selected from the value

Tags: node.js, pug, dropdown

How do I mark an option selected base on the parsedValue? eg. if the parsedValue is 0, then the option with value 0 should be selected. If parsedValue is 1, then the option with value 1 should be selected?

Code :

```
parsedValue = 0;

select#myDD.b.pa2.input-reset.ba.bg-transparent.hover-bg-black.hover-white.w-100(type='text', name='myDD')
 option(label='zero', value='0')
  | Space Type
 option(label='first', value='1')
  | Space Type
 option(label='second', value='2')
  | Space Type
 option(label='third', value='3')
  | Space Type
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a good case for using a [mixin](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html):

```
- var parsedValue = 2

mixin option
  option(selected= (attributes.value == parsedValue))&attributes(attributes)
    if block
      block

select
  +option(label='zero',   value='0') Option 0
  +option(label='first',  value='1') Option 1
  +option(label='second', value='2') Option 2
  +option(label='third',  value='3') Option 3
```

This is a parameterless mixin that takes advantage of the [implicit `attributes` argument](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html#mixin-attributes). Whatever attributes you provide when calling the mixin will be reflected on the rendered `option` element.

Additionally, it conditionally sets the `selected` attribute if the value of the `value` attribute matches the `parsedValue` variable.

Note: While one would expect the selected `option` to render with `selected="true"`, and the other `option` elements to render with `selected="false"`, Pug is [smart enough with boolean attributes](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#boolean-attributes) to clean this up and use `selected="selected"` or omit the attribute altogether.

The resulting HTML:

```
<select>
  <option label="zero" value="0">Option 0</option>
  <option label="first" value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option selected="selected" label="second" value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option label="third" value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```